# AIX Enable IOCP without smitty

Tags: aix, iocp

Hey I wanted to automate the process where I would be able to automate the process of enabling (making available) the I/O completion port (IOCP) in aix.

For some reason when I look around everywhere it says to use smitty, to enable it. Is it possible to do it without the use of smitty and if so how?

Or does anyone now if i was to still use smitty can I automate the process using a script?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the procedure. 
Since smit (smitty) runs external commands it was running mkdev -l iocp0 to make IOCP available

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that you can check its status with the lsdev command:

```
lsdev -Cc iocp
```

Answer (score 2):

The two commands you need are:

## mkdev -l iocp0

## chdev -l iocp0 -P -a autoconfig='available'

The second makes sure it comes back available, otherwise when you reboot it could go back to "defined".

Answer (score 1):

you can always get to know the underlying command which smitty executes by smiply pressing (esc + 6 ) .

COMMAND STATUS

Command: OK            stdout: yes           stderr: no

Before command completion, additional instructions may appear below.

iocp0 Available

```
                                                        ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                                                        │                           SHOW COMMAND STRING                            │
                                                        │                                                                          │
                                                        │ Press Enter or Cancel to return to the                                   │
                                                        │ application.                                                             │
                                                        │                                                                          │
                                                        │   mkdev -l iocp0                                                         │
                                                        │                                                                          │
```

F1=Help                                          F2=Refresh │ F1=Help                 F2=Refresh              F3=Cancel                │           Esc+6=Command
Esc+8=Image                                      Esc+9=Shell│ Esc+8=Image             Esc+0=Exit              Enter=Do                 │           /=Find
n=Find Next                                                 └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘